# Cordova 3.6 assets update for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I hope that the focus of this question is not too large... 
But I guess many people have the same difficulties, as it's really not user friendly in my opinion.

I recently updated my Android Project from Cordova 2.4 to Cordova 3.6. I created a new project in Eclipse ADT, and imported the previous assets.

Well, I finally end up with this folder structure

[image: Project Structure]

I finally have two `www` folders, and one `platform_www` folder which includes `cordova.js`.

The app does not seem to be updated when I change those assets files.

So, where is the real working directory of the assets?
If some folders should be merged, how do I force this merging?
Which ideal process should I follow for iterative testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is the process I ended up with:

1. I only use Eclipse to have access to the console. I created a filter to only display  the `CordovaLog` tag
2. I update the files located in `myproject/www`
3. I run the application using the CLI (*not Eclipse*): `cordova run android`